# Install Umbraco 4.8.1 fails to compile

Tags: compilation, umbraco, virtual-path

I have installed a new site with Umbraco 4.8.1 and the first thing I try to do is to build the project, but I get this error :

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\UmbracoAlden\umbraco\developer\RelationTypes\NewRelationType.aspx(1): Build (web): The virtual path '/umbraco/masterpages/umbracoPage.Master' maps to another application, which is not allowed.
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you attempting to build the website application, or are you trying to compile it from the source?

Comment: How did you installed that new site? Please give more informations. This error occurs during the attempt of compiling the application..